# ¿Reutilizar layouts similares en Android es una buena práctica? ¿Qué pasa con tools:context en ese caso?

Tags: android, layout, buenas-prácticas

Tengo cerca de 30 actividades que usan layouts similares.

Los layouts se han ido creando en la medida en que he ido creando cada actividad. Viendo que la cosa va creciendo, me pregunto si sería conveniente **reutilizar layouts**.

Aquí muestro dos:

#### Un layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.SantosActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_breviario_general" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### Otro layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.ComentariosActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_breviario_general" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Como pueden ver, la única diferencia entre ambos es lo relativo a `tools:context`, todo lo demás es idéntico.

Entonces, ¿podría usar un sólo layout para todas esas actividades que usan un layout casi idéntico? ¿cómo podría hacerlo? ¿qué implicaciones tendría el asunto de `tools:context` (leyendo en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11078487/5587982)) lo que he entendido es que esto ayuda en la carga del UI, en los listeners, etc, pero no me queda claro)?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, ¿Has evaluado usar Fragments en lugar de Actividades, o es requisito en este caso usar Activities ?

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys no lo he evaluado, no hay requisito pre-establecido. He usado Actividades porque se gestiona código diferente generalmente servido por una API y/o por Firebase.[Esta es la pantalla inicial](https://www.flickr.com/photos/144291848@N08/43235841245), desde cada cuadro se llama a una Actividad  y dentro de esos cuadros algunos llaman a otra serie de posibilidades, por ejemplo [una subpantalla](https://www.flickr.com/photos/144291848@N08/44095309852/in/album-72157694572903730/). Hay contenido similar, pero cambia la fuente de datos y la estructura de los mismos.

Comment: Debo decir que nunca he usado Fragmentos en Android. ¿Crees que serían una solución para mi caso? Otra cosa que debo decir es que uso Gson y que mapeo las respuestas a clases de mi modelo, facilitando bastante la presentación del contenido, el cual es algo complejo porque maneja mucho texto, y varios tipos de formato pero tengo métodos en las clases para las construcciones complicadas, liberando así a las Actividades de gran contenido de código.

Answer (score 0):

De hecho deberías de reutilizar siempre que se pueda porque de no hacerlo implicaría tener que cambiar cada uno, uno por uno cada vez que haya que cambiar algo en la UI, y eso conlleva a inconsistencias y potenciales errores, además el tiempo que tomaría hacerlo se empieza a hacer inviable. Precisamente para casos como esos están pensados los Fragments. Y con respecto a lo de `tools:context` eso es algo que quedaría en la raíz de cada layout sin ningún problema. El o los Fragments irían dentro de ese nodo raíz.